# Are there general formula I could use to simplify/shorten my derivations of the expected value of the biased sample variance?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance

In the derivation for the expected value of the (biased) sample variance, there were some intermediate equalities shown below and I wanted to check them myself:

$$
\frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^k\mathbb{E}\left\{\left[x(j) - \frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^{k}x(i)\right]^2\right\} = \frac{1}{k^3}\sum_{j=1}^k\mathbb{E}\left\{\left[(k-1)x(j) - \sum_{\substack{i=1 \\ i\neq j}}x(i)\right]^2\right\} = \frac{1}{k^2}[(k-1)^2 + k - 1]\sigma_0^2,
$$
where $\sigma_0^2$ is the true variance of the i.i.d. random variable $x(j) \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_0^2)$ at every discrete time step $j$.

My attempts are shown below and I am almost convinced with them. However, it took me quite long and I feel like I am missing out on a few general/known identities that could be used to make derivations simpler.

For example, I am wondering if there are formulas for squaring sums of such forms, or if taking the expectation operator earlier can reduce some steps with known identities.

It would be great if I can get my derivations verified, and awesome if you can point out some known formula to shorten some steps.

**Attempt for first equality:**

For the first equality, I tried to rearrange the expression inside the expectation first as below
\begin{align}
\left[x(j) - \frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^{k}x(i)\right]^2 &= [x(j)]^2 +\frac{1}{k^2}\left[\sum_{i=1}^k x(i)\right]^2 - \frac{2}{k}x(j)\cdot\sum_{i=1}^kx(i) \\
&=\frac{1}{k^2}\cdot\left\{k^2[x(j)]^2 + \left[\sum_{i=1}^k x(i)\right]^2- 2k\cdot x(j)\sum_{i=1}^kx(i) \right\},
\end{align}

So now I can factor out $\frac{1}{k^2}$ outside of the expectation and just work with the expression inside $\{\cdot\}$.

\begin{align}
k^2[x(j)]^2 + \left[\sum_{i=1}^k x(i)\right]^2- 2k\cdot x(j)\sum_{i=1}^kx(i) = k^2[x(j)]^2 +\left[\sum_{i=1}^k x(i)\right]^2 - 2k\cdot[x(j)]^2 -2k\cdot x(j)\sum_{\substack{i=1 \\ i\neq j}}^kx(i) \\
 = k^2[x(j)]^2 - 2k\cdot[x(j)]^2 + \left[[x(j)]^2 + \sum_{\substack{i=1 \\ i\neq j}}^k[x(i)]^2 + 2\sum_{\substack{i = 1 \\ i\neq{j}}}^kx(i)\cdot x(j)\right] -2k\cdot x(j)\cdot \sum_{\substack{i=1 \\ i\neq j}}^kx(i) \\
 = (k^2 - 2k + 1)\cdot[x(j)]^2 + \left[\sum_{\substack{i=1 \\ i\neq j}}^k[x(i)]^2 + 2\sum_{i\neq{j}}^kx(i)\cdot x(j) -2k\cdot x(j)\cdot \sum_{\substack{i=1 \\ i\neq j}}^kx(i)\right] \\
 = [(k-1)\cdot x(j)]^2 + \left[\sum_{\substack{i=1 \\ i\neq j}}^k[x(i)]^2 + 2\sum_{i\neq{j}}^kx(i)\cdot x(j) -2k\cdot x(j)\cdot \sum_{\substack{i=1 \\ i\neq j}}^kx(i)\right]
\end{align}

It would be great if I can make the square braket term equal to $-2(k-1)x(j)\sum_{\substack{i=1 \\ i\neq j}}^kx(i) + [\sum_{\substack{i=1 \\ i\neq j}}^kx(i)]^2$ to complete the square of the RHS and some terms like $[\sum_{\substack{i=1 \\ i\neq j}}^kx(i)]^2$and $-2kx(j)\sum_{\substack{i=1 \\ i\neq j}}^kx(i)$ are already there.

I am a bit uncertain about this but $2x(j)\sum_{\substack{i=1 \\ i\neq j}}^kx(i)$ equals to $2\sum_{i\neq{j}}^kx(i)\cdot x(j)$, therefore:

$$
k^2[x(j)]^2 + \left[\sum_{i=1}^k x(i)\right]^2- 2k\cdot x(j)\sum_{i=1}^kx(i) = \left[(k-1)\cdot x(j) - \sum_{\substack{i=1 \\ i\neq j}}^kx(i)\right]^2,
$$

arriving at the first equality.

**Attempt for second equality:**

$$
\frac{1}{k^3}\sum_{j=1}^k\mathbb{E}\left\{\left[(k-1)x(j) - \sum_{\substack{i=1 \\ i\neq j}}x(i)\right]^2\right\}  \\
= \frac{1}{k^3}\sum_{j=1}^k\mathbb{E}\left\{[(k-1)\cdot x(j)]^2-2(k-1)x(j)\sum_{\substack{i=1 \\ i\neq j}}^kx(i) + \left[\sum_{\substack{i=1 \\ i\neq j}}^kx(i)\right]^2\right\}\\
=\frac{1}{k^3}\sum_{j=1}^k \left[(k-1)^2 \sigma_0^2 -2(k-1)\require{cancel}\cancelto{0}{\mathbb{E}\left\{x(j) \sum_{\substack{i=1 \\ i\neq j}}^kx(i)\right\}} + \mathbb{E}\left\{ \left[\sum_{\substack{i=1 \\ i\neq j}}^kx(i)\right]^2\right\} \right] \\
=\frac{1}{k^3}\sum_{j=1}^k \left[(k-1)^2 \sigma_0^2 + \mathbb{E}\left\{ \sum_{\substack{i=1 \\ i\neq j}}^k [x(i)]^2 + 2\sum_{\substack{i=1 \\ i\neq j}}^k x(i)\cdot x(j) \right\} \right]\\
=\frac{1}{k^3}\sum_{j=1}^k \left[(k-1)^2 \sigma_0^2 + (k-1) \sigma_0^2 \right]\\
=\frac{1}{k^2} \left[(k-1)^2 \sigma_0^2 + (k-1) \sigma_0^2 \right],
$$
arriving at the second equality.

Comment: Have you thought of using vector notion?  This could simply your derivation and formulas. Could you define $x(j)$ and $x(i)$ above?  Are these the equivalent of $x_i$ and $x_j$?

Comment: @StatsStudent, I am not sure how I can convert to a correct vector form. Do you have any suggestions for a starting point? And yes I will define them more clearly in the edit now. They are the same $x$ but at different time indexes.

Comment: On the first line, you've defined the sample variance with a denominator of $1/k$. But the sample variance, $S^2$ is defined as $S^2=\frac{1}{k-1}\sum_{i=1}^{k}\left(X_{i}-\bar{X}\right)^{2}$

Comment: @StatsStudent, right that is for an unbiased sample variance. I am looking at the biased sample variance, sorry I will make it clear in the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "biased variance" is equivalent to a scaled sample variance
given by: $\frac{(k-1)}{k}S^{2}=\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^{k}\left(X_{i}-\bar{X}\right)^{2}$

So we can derive the expected value of this as follows:

\begin{eqnarray*}
E\left[\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^{k}\left(X_{i}-\bar{X}\right)^{2}\right] & = & \frac{1}{k}E\left[\sum_{i=1}^{k}\left(X_{i}^{2}-2X_{i}\bar{X}+\bar{X}^{2}\right)\right]\\
 & = & \frac{1}{k}E\left[\sum_{i=1}^{k}X_{i}^{2}-2\bar{X}\sum_{i=1}^{k}X_{i}+\sum_{i=1}^{k}\bar{X}^{2}\right]\\
 & = & \frac{1}{k}E\left[\sum_{i=1}^{k}X_{i}^{2}-2\bar{X}\sum_{i=1}^{k}X_{i}+\sum_{i=1}^{k}\bar{X}^{2}\right]\\
 & = & \frac{1}{k}E\left[\sum_{i=1}^{k}X_{i}^{2}-2\bar{X}\frac{k}{k}\sum_{i=1}^{k}X_{i}+k\bar{X}^{2}\right]\\
 & = & \frac{1}{k}E\left[\sum_{i=1}^{k}X_{i}^{2}-2k\bar{X}^{2}+k\bar{X}^{2}\right]\\
 & = & \frac{1}{k}E\left[\sum_{i=1}^{k}X_{i}^{2}-k\bar{X}^{2}\right]\\
 & = & \frac{1}{k}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{k}E\left(X_{i}^{2}\right)-kE\left(\bar{X}^{2}\right)\right]\\
 & = & \frac{1}{k}\left[kE\left(X_{i}^{2}\right)-kE\left(\bar{X}^{2}\right)\right]\\
 & = & E\left(X_{i}^{2}\right)-E\left(\bar{X}^{2}\right)\\
 & = & \sigma_{0}^{2}+\mu^{2}-\left(\frac{\sigma_{0}^{2}}{k}+\mu^{2}\right)\\
 & = & \sigma_{0}^{2}+\mu^{2}-\frac{\sigma_{0}^{2}}{k}-\mu^{2}\\
 & = & \sigma_{0}^{2}-\frac{\sigma_{0}^{2}}{k}\\
 & = & \sigma_{0}^{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)
\end{eqnarray*}

Now, notice the second line of your first equation block is given
by:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{k^{2}}\left[\left(k-1\right)^{2}+k-1\right]\sigma_{0}^{2} & = & \frac{1}{k^{2}}\left[k^{2}-2k+1+k-1\right]\sigma_{0}^{2}\\
 & = & \frac{1}{k^{2}}\left[k^{2}-k\right]\sigma_{0}^{2}\\
 & = & \sigma_{0}^{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)\\
\end{eqnarray*}

Since this matches the result above, we have shown they are equivalent,
and the expected value is given by $\sigma_{0}^{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)$.
$\blacksquare$

**Additional Comments based on Comment**
You were right, that I had my signs incorrect and $E(\bar{X}^2)=\left(\frac{\sigma_{0}^{2}}{k}+\mu^{2}\right)$.

The term $\left(\frac{\sigma_{0}^{2}}{k}+\mu^{2}\right)$ comes from the identity that for any random variable $Y$, the variance can be written as $Var(Y)=E(Y^2)-E(Y)^2$.  In the case above, however, we have the random variable $\bar{X}$, so we can write $Var(\bar{X})=E(\bar{X}^2)-E(\bar{X})^2$.  It's is easily shown that $Var(\bar{X}) = \frac{\sigma^2_0}{k}$.  To see we have:
\begin{eqnarray*}
Var(\bar{X}) & = & Var\left[\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^{k}X_{i}\right]\\
 & = & \frac{1}{k^{2}}Var\left[\sum_{i=1}^{k}X_{i}\right]\\
 & = & \frac{1}{k^{2}}\sum_{i=1}^{k}Var\left(X_{i}\right)\\
 & = & \frac{1}{k^{2}}kVar\left(X_{i}\right)\begin{array}{ccc}
 &  & (\text{by independence of each $X_i$})\end{array}\\
 & = & \frac{1}{k}\sigma_{o}^{2}
\end{eqnarray*}

**Response to comment about squaring a constant in a variance**

You indicated that you weren't " understanding how a constant ($k$) multiplied to the argument of variance comes out squared."  Here's a way to understand that and prove it to yourself.  This uses the variance identity I described in my previous comment section above:

\begin{eqnarray*}
Var(kX) & = & E[\left(kX\right)^{2}]-E[kX]^{2}\\
 & = & E[\left(k^{2}X^{2}\right)]-E[kX]^{2}\\
 & = & k^{2}E[\left(X^{2}\right)]-[kE(X)]^{2}\\
 & = & k^{2}E[X^{2}]-k^{2}E(X)^{2}\\
 & = & k^{2}\left\{ E[X^{2}]-E(X)^{2}\right\} \\
 & = & k^{2}\left\{ \sigma_{0}^{2}\right\} \\
 & = & k^{2}\sigma_{0}^{2}
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Is there a name for $E(\bar{X}^2) = (\frac{\sigma_0^2}{k} - \mu^2)$, could you expand on that equality please? Also, should it be $+$ instead? I don't understand in particular how to see $\frac{\sigma_0^2}{k}$.

Comment: @js9, you are right!  I had a sign reversal and this should have been a plus sign (see my Additional Comments based on Comment" above.

Comment: thanks! So according to that equation, $Var(\bar{X}^2) = \frac{\sigma_0^2}{k}$ since the mean squared is $\mu^2$, but I don't understand  $Var(\bar{X}^2) = \frac{\sigma_0^2}{k}$.

Firstly, do you mean to say $Var(\bar{X})$ instead?
In that case, since the variance of a sum is a sum of variances, and $\bar{X} = \frac{\sum_{i =1}^k X_i}{k}$, wouldn't it be $Var(\bar{X}) = \frac{k\cdot Var(X_i)}{k} = Var(X_i) = \sigma_0$ instead? If you did mean  $Var(\bar{X}^2)$, I don't know why it's immediately equal to $\frac{\sigma_0^2}{k}$

Comment: I added a bit more above and edited. And yes, I had an a square in there by accident!  Sorry about that!   Also, don't forget to square the $1/k$ when you move it outside the $Var(.)$ term.

Comment: @StasStudent, thanks very much again for elaborating more, so $Var(Y^2)$ should be $Var(Y)$ as well, right?

Comment: Ugh.  Yes.  That's what I get for copying and pasting!  My apologies.  Fixing now.

Comment: @js9, do you fully understand the derivation now?  Is anything else unclear to you?

Comment: Yes! Turns out I wasn't understanding how a constant multiplied to the argument of variance comes out squared. It's super clear now and much simpler than how I did, thanks very much!

Comment: @js9, great!  One other comment.  I've assumed throughout, based on your anticipated answer, that the $X_i$'s are independent.  If they are not independent, then the answer (and proof) becomes more complicated because if they are not independent, then the variance of a sum is equal to the sum of the variance plus twice the sum of the covariances, rather than just the sum of the variance.

Comment: @js9, I added a little proof at the very end above to help you understand why the constant term is squared when you pull it outside the Variance term.  Best of luck in your studies!